# Android scroll a FrameLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-5.0-lollipop

So I'm adding CardViews in a FrameLayout and they get stacked on top of each other. Now what I need is to scroll through those cards so that one comes under the other downwards while I scroll down. Much like in Android lollipop when you scroll your notifications.

Comment: A scrollview can only have one child;

Comment: Yes but the think is the FramaLayout will handle scrolling (moving each child) and not a ScrollView.

Comment: Can you use ObjectAnimators hooked to whatever is scrolling?